# Reduce a string when it has a pair

Tags: string, c++14

Shil has a string S , consisting of N lowercase English letters. In one operation, he can delete any pair of adjacent letters with same value. For example, string "aabcc" would become either "aab" or "bcc" after operation.

Shil wants to reduce S as much as possible. To do this, he will repeat the above operation as many times as it can be performed. Help Shil out by finding and printing 's non-reducible form!

If the final string is empty, print Empty String; otherwise, print the final non-reducible string.

Sample Input 0

aaabccddd

Sample Output 0

abd

Sample Input 1

baab

Sample Output 1

Empty String

Sample Input 2

aa

Sample Output 2

Empty String
Explanation

Sample Case 0: Shil can perform the following sequence of operations to get the final string:

Thus, we print .

Sample Case 1: Shil can perform the following sequence of operations to get the final string: aaabccddd -> abccddd

abccddd -> abddd

abddd -> abd

Thus we print abd

Sample case 1: baab -> bb

bb -> Empty String.

in my code in the while loop when i assign s[i] to str[i].the value of s[i] is not getting assigned to str[i].the str[i] has a garbage value.

my code :

```
     int main() {
     /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
    string s;
cin>>s;
int len = s.length();
int len1 = 0;
string str;
for(int i = 0;i < len-1;i++){
    if(s[i]!= '*'){
       for(int j=i+1;j < len;j++){
           if(s[j] != '*'){
               if(s[i] == s[j]){
                   s[i] = s[j] = '*';
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
int i = 0;
while(i<len){
    if(s[i] != '*'){
        str[len1] = s[i];
        len1++;

    }
    i++;
}


if(len1 != 0){
    cout<<str;

}
else{
    cout<<"Empty String";
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Seems ambiguous. What does it mean to "do it as many times as possible"? Do you start over as soon as the first pair in encountered?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string s,tempS;
bool condition = false;
cin >> s;
tempS = s;
while(condition==false){
    for(int i=1; i<s.size(); i++){
        if(s[i]==s[i-1]){
            s.erase(s.begin()+i-1, s.begin()+i+1);
        }
    }
    if(tempS == s){
        condition = true;
    } else{
        tempS = s;
    }
}

if(s.size()==0){
    cout << "Empty String" ;
} else{
    cout << s;
}

return 0;
}
```

the first while loop keeps on modifying the string until and unless it becomes equal to temp (which is equal to the string pre-modification)
It is comparing the adjacent elements if they are equal or not and then deleting them both. 
As soon as string becomes equal to temp after modifications, string has reached it's most reduced state !

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful.  Please include a paragraph highlighting what the code does or the logic used.